# Docbook Dblatex - how to omit header on first page of chapter?

Tags: docbook, dblatex

I'm using dblatex to convert a book formatted using Docbook into a PDf, and everything is working great, however for the life of me I can't figure out how to suppress the inclusion of a header on the first page of each chapter? Of course I want that page to "count" in terms of the overall page count, however I don't want the book title nor page number to appear on that first page.

Any ideas?

Thank you!
Jason

Answer (score 0):

In latex this is often done using a combo of the fancyhdr package and the \thispagestyle{} command. I would look through your dsssl stylesheet for references to these packages.